# Create app to be used as screensaver when Android device is charging

Tags: android

In the android settings ( Version 8.0) under display there is an option to set a screensaver for when your device is charging. There are four options, Colours, Photo Frame, Photo Table and Photos. I was wondering if it is possible to create an app that can be used as another option here?